# Get paragraphs after a certain symbol: need better output

Tags: python, text, extract, paragraph

I‘m a python beginner.

I have this code that get‘s all paragraphs after the symbols ‘*****‘

```
import re


file = open('/Users/simon/DRIVE/ARCHIVED/Tools at Hand/PASTE.txt', mode='r')

result = [s.strip() for s in re.findall(r'^\*{4,}((?:\r?\n(?!\s*$|\*{4}).+)*)', file.read(), 

re.MULTILINE)]



print(result)
file.close()
```

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

****
Sed id placerat magna.

*******
Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique. 

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.
```

The output I need:

```
Sed id placerat magna.

Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.
```

The output I get:

```
'Sed id placerat magna.', 'Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.'
```

I can‘t seem to figure out how to output each sentence per paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list with the values of the capture group.

You could for example [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) the list prepending `*` to unpack the `result` and set the separator to 2 newlines.

```
import re

file = open('/Users/simon/DRIVE/ARCHIVED/Tools at Hand/PASTE.txt', mode='r')

result = [s.strip() for s in re.findall(r'^\*{4,}((?:\r?\n(?!\s*$|\*{4}).+)*)', file.read(), re.MULTILINE)]

print(*result, sep="\n\n")

file.close()
```

Output

```
Sed id placerat magna.

Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.
```